# Aplicativo fechando inesperadamente ao enviar requisição post

Tags: android, android-fragment

Bom estou desenvolvendo uma tela utilizando o `holder view` e nela estou enviando um `JSON` para o servidor, porém tem dado problema. Ao clicar no botão enviar ele simplesmente fecha a aplicação, e no log de erro não aparece nada.

O que poderia ser o problema? Irei colocar todo meu `fragment` para que vocês deem uma olhada:

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_indique_restaurante)
public class FragmentIndique extends Fragment {

@ViewById
EditText txtIndicacao;

RetornoLogin cliente;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_indique_restaurante, container, false);
    Button btnEnviar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnviarIndicacao);

    btnEnviar.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            enviarIndicacao();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.toolbar_title);
    toolbarTitle.setText(R.string.menu_recomende_restaurante);
}

public void enviarIndicacao(){

    //cliente = (RetornoLogin) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(CLIENTE);

    String txtObs = txtIndicacao.getText().toString();
   // retornoLogin.getCliente().getNomeCliente()

    try{

        //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(txtObs);
        JSONObject my_obj = new JSONObject();
        my_obj.put("titulo", "JSON x XML: a Batalha Final");
        my_obj.put("ano", 2012);
        my_obj.put("genero", "Ação");


        final AsyncHttpClient request = new AsyncHttpClient();
        request.addHeader("Authorization", Constantes.TOKEN_SERVIDOR);

        // Parametros
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("cliente", my_obj);

        // Exibe a mensagem de progresso
        final ProgressDialog progress = MessageUtil.showProgress(getActivity(), R.string.aguarde, R.string.enviando_indicacao, true);
        final Context mContext = getContext();

        progress.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                request.cancelRequests(mContext, true);
            }
        });
        progress.show();

        request.post(Constantes.URL_CADASTRO, params,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String resposta) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                        sucessoResposta(resposta);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                        falhaResposta(t);
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
        MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), R.string.erro_desconhecido);
    }
}

private void sucessoResposta(String resposta) {

    RetornoLogin retornoLogin;

    try {
        // Desserializa a resposta
        retornoLogin = JSONParser.parseLogin(resposta);

        // Conseguiu desserializar a resposta, verifica se houve sucesso
        if (retornoLogin.isSucesso()) {

        } else {
            // Exibe a mensagem de erro
            MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), ResourceUtil.getString(retornoLogin.getMensagem()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Falha ao desserializar objeto, exibe uma mensagem
        MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), R.string.erro_desconhecido);
        NegocioLog.inserir(Log.AVISO, e);
        return;
    }

}

private void falhaResposta(Throwable t) {
    // Envia para o servidor o log de erro
    MessageUtil.showError(getActivity(), R.string.erro_desconhecido_ws);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, se esse for o código todo, há um erro em 'txtIndicacao'. Ele nunca é inicializado, está fora do seu try-catch, deve ser por isso que você não consegue capturar os logs. Aparentemente o erro é logo nessa primeira linha, que provavelmente retorna null, já que não conhece o seu componente chamado 'txtIndicacao'.

Comment: Vou testar para ver

Comment: Faltou você dizer qual é esse componente, igual fez em:::  Button btnEnviar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEnviarIndicacao);

Comment: Brother nem foi necessário, foi apenas passar para dentro do try e pronto.

Comment: Show, mas tenha em mente que no futuro, se você precisar usar esse texto, vai dar erro pois não foi inicializado. Ai no caso é simples, só apontar no seu arquivo R.java, exatamente como fez para o botão :) abraço!

Comment: Sim ja acertei aqui